# Getting error about logical vs. double vector when subsetting

Tags: r, subset

In R, I used Rosner's test `EnvStats::rosnerTest` to identify outliers in my dataset. My end goal is to have a vector of row numbers in my dataset where `Outlier = TRUE`.

```r
var.ros.test <- rosnerTest(df$var, k = 20)
class(var.ros.test)
[1] "gofOutlier"
print(var.ros.test$all.stats)
```

This is the output of `var.ros.test$all.stats`. I highlighted the Obs.Num that I want to save in a vector when `Outlier = TRUE`.

[image]

I started this code but I am stuck because this code returns all Obs.Num, when I only want Obs.Num when `Outlier = TRUE`.

```r
var.out <- subset(var.ros.test$all.stats, select = "Obs.Num")
print(var.out)
      Obs.Num
1      977
2      91
3      384
4      97
5      281
.
.
.
```

```r
> class(var.out)
[1] "data.frame"

> var.out <- var.out[,1]
> var.out <- as.vector(var.out) %>% unlist(var.out)
> print(var.out)
[1]  977   91  384   97  281   65  512  331    6 1041   39
[12]    2  147   69  856  133  329  577 1017  104
```

Which would be fine, except this contains Row.Obs where `Outlier = FALSE`.

Previously, I tried doing this:

```r
var.out <- subset(var.ros.test$all.stats, select = "Obs.Num") %>%
filter(var.ros.test$all.stats, Outlier == "TRUE")
```

But I get `"Error in filter(): ℹ In argument: var.ros.test$all.stats. Caused by error:! ..1$i must be a logical vector, not a double vector."`

I would greatly appreciate any tips on how to get a vector of Row.Obs when `Outlier = TRUE`. Thank you so much!

Comment: are you using dplyr for filter? try to remove var.ros.test$all.stats from the filter statement

Comment: I have dplyr and tidyverse loaded - not sure which one is doing the filtering actually. I did what you suggested and got this error: "Error in `filter()`: ℹ In argument: `Outlier == TRUE`.   Caused by error: ! object 'Outlier' not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem, but you're using a character string "TRUE" for filtering. I assume *Outlier* is a logical boolean vector.

If this is your data

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(dat = 1:10, 
                 sam = sample(10), 
                 Outlier = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=T))

df
   dat sam Outlier
1    1   1    TRUE
2    2   5   FALSE
3    3  10    TRUE
4    4   8   FALSE
5    5   2    TRUE
6    6   4    TRUE
7    7   6   FALSE
8    8   9   FALSE
9    9   7   FALSE
10  10   3   FALSE
```

with *Outlier* s class being

```
class(df$Outlier)
[1] "logical"
```

then `filter` only needs the variable, since it's already a logical boolean.

```
df %>% filter(Outlier)
  dat sam Outlier
1   1   1    TRUE
2   3  10    TRUE
3   5   2    TRUE
4   6   4    TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get where I needed to be. This is the code that worked:

    var.ros.test <- rosnerTest(pb$pot, k = 20)
    
    ros.results <- var.ros.test$all.stats

    var.out <- ros.results %>% filter(Outlier) %>% select(Obs.Num)

    pot.out <- pot.out[,1] #to make it a vector instead of a DF

Comment: @burphound Nice, glad it helped!

Comment: (1/2) I tried to automate this with a function but get an error:

detect.outlier <- function(df, i, k) {  # i is a column/variable, and k is an input in the Rosner test

  plot(df$year, df[[i]], xlab = "Year", ylab = "Value") # I also want to print the plot

  ros.test <- rosnerTest(df[[i]], k)

  ros.results <- ros.test$all.stats

  ros.outliers <- ros.results %>% filter(Outlier) %>% select(Obs.Num)

  ros.outliers <- ros.outliers[,1]  # change from a data frame to a vector 

  outlier_df <- df[df$row %in% ros.outliers,]

  return(outlier_df %>% select(age_class, sex, i))

}

Comment: (2/2) My goal with this function is to take a column in my data frame, identify the outliers, and return a new data frame so I can inspect each outlier. But when I call the function I get "Error during wrapup: recursive indexing failed at level 2. Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart". I've tried debugging but no luck. Do you have any tips?

Comment: @burphound Hmm, thats very difficult to diagnose without an example. Also, the comment format makes it hard to parse through the code. Maybe open a new question? Make sure you include a minimal reproducible example using `dput(head(data))` if possible.

Comment: Thank you! I just posted it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76048208/error-when-creating-function-recursive-indexing-failed

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

Let's say your data frame after rosnerTest is df:

```
my_vector <- df$Obs.Num[df$Outlier==TRUE]

# or 

my_vector <- df$obs.Num[df$Outlier]

my_vector
 [1]  977   91  384   97  281   65  512  331    6 1041
[11]   39    2  147   69  856  133
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(i = 0:19, Mean.i = c(4.642206, 4.499109, 4.495698, 
4.492713, 4.489818, 4.487015, 4.484331, 4.48697, 4.484542, 4.482255, 
4.480011, 4.48222, 4.48004, 4.477982, 4.480001, 4.478066, 4.476223, 
4.474543, 4.476177, 4.474591), SD.i = c(4.6533734, 0.5447116, 
0.5337232, 0.525215, 0.5171029, 0.5093903, 0.5022408, 0.4952362, 
0.4892673, 0.4839342, 0.4787576, 0.473692, 0.468713, 0.4642559, 
0.4599334, 0.4559441, 0.4523224, 0.4493255, 0.4464857, 0.4438066
), Value = c(153.75, 8.05, 7.6, 7.5, 7.4, 7.27, 1.75, 7, 6.85, 
6.8, 2.2, 6.73, 6.6, 2.4, 6.47, 6.37, 6.2, 2.8, 6.1, 2.9), Obs.Num = c(977L, 
91L, 384L, 97L, 281L, 65L, 512L, 331L, 6L, 1041L, 39L, 2L, 147L, 
69L, 856L, 133L, 329L, 577L, 1017L, 104L), R.i.1 = c(32.042946, 
6.518847, 5.816314, 5.725821, 5.627857, 5.463365, 5.444263, 5.074407, 
4.834694, 4.789381, 4.762349, 4.745234, 4.522938, 4.47594, 4.32671, 
4.149488, 3.810947, 3.726794, 3.636898, 3.547922), lambda.i.1 = c(4.050338, 
4.050102, 4.049866, 4.04963, 4.049394, 4.049157, 4.048921, 4.048684, 
4.048446, 4.048209, 4.047971, 4.047733, 4.047494, 4.047256, 4.047017, 
4.046778, 4.046538, 4.046299, 4.046059, 4.045819), Outlier = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```